# fill character array by blocks

Tags: c, arrays, casting

question of curiosity
suppose I have:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[32];
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        str[i] = 0;
}
```

but I want to do it 4x faster

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[32];
    for (i = 0; i < 32 / 4; i += 4)
        str[i] = (int)0;
}
```

I expect that the whole array will be filled with zeros.
but array is not filled by zeroes

my questions: why array not filled by zeroes? how to fill array per int blocks? my question is Research for c feature, how to tell the compiler - write blocks of 4 bytes, ie integer registers, it will reduce the number of memory accesses by 4 times, on x64 processors reduce 8 times

thanks for all, follows work well:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char str[32];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                str[i] = 12;
        for (i = 0; i < 32 / sizeof(int); i++)
                ((int *) str)[i] = 0;
        printf("%d\n", i);
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                printf("%d\n", str[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The type of `0` itself is `int`, `(int)0` is not different from `0`.

Comment: What do you mean by 4x faster? All your doing is skipping 3 blocks every time you loop

Comment: It's a stack variable, so writing `char str[32] = {'\0'};` will initialize the entire block

Comment: `((int *) str)[i] = 0x00000000` can result in unaligned access, [take a look](http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html)

Comment: no, if size_of_array % sizeof(int) == 0, and sizeof(int) == 4

Comment: @IvanIvanovich, you are wrong, `str` can be placed in a misaligned address for `int` (e.g. not a multiple of 4) `((int *) str)[i] = 0;` is UB

Comment: yes, you're right, it is necessary to check the starting address of the array.

Comment: but my question was research for pointers and casts

Comment: @IvanIvanovich, the only way to run your code in a safe-mode is checking `__alignof__(int)` and placing `str` in a  multiple of the result, this is a hard task and note that `__alignof_` is a GNU compiler extension

Comment: @IvanIvanovich, you are welcome,you have a new answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The correct and fastest way is to initialize the array to zero

```
char str[32] = { 0 } ;
```

If you want to set the array to zero afterwards, then use memset and enable compiler optimization and intrinsic functions, and the compiler will figure out the fastest way to zero the array.

```
memset( str , 0 , sizeof( str ) ) ;
```

Comment: yes, of course, but my question is Research for c feature

how to tell the compiler - write blocks of 4 bytes, ie integer registers, it will reduce the number of memory accesses by 4 times, on x64 processors reduce 8 times

Comment: @IvanIvanovich: Who's to say that an int will be 4 bytes? The standard defines an int as being _at least 16 bits_ in size. 2 bytes or more...

Comment: on x32 and x64 machine int is 32 bits, ie 4 bytes. chort is 16 bits

Comment: @IvanIvanovich: That's what many `memset` implementations already do. My `glibc` on x64 uses chunks of 8 bytes if possible (not 4, although that's the size of an `int` on my machine), for example. If you want to do that yourself, you need to worry about alignment and strict aliasing. If you're interested how `memcpy` is implemented, look at the source code of a free implementation.

Comment: @IvanIvanovich: In most cases. But an valid implementation of the standard where `sizeof(int)` is 2 is plausible. Likely? Not really. Possible: Sure. Just like it is possible to have a C implementation where a `char` is 1 Mb in size, if that's the smallest addressable unit on some alien machine

Comment: There are many implementations, there exist where one byte equals 6 bits

Comment: This is all solved with *math*, not platform *assumptions*.  There are many assumptions about `sizeof char` and `sizeof int` in Ivan's code.  These assumptions are unnecessary and dangerous.  Even if a coder is 100% certain their code will never run on x32 or x64 or xYZ, they still have little excuse to not use the macros provided to us like `CHAR_BIT` or (especially) the `sizeof` operator.  If a 32 bit `int` is what you want, simply use `int32_t`. Later, if a future platform doesn't support that size then at least you'll know at compile time. Safe coding like this has no performance penalty.

Comment: Follow-up question: if `memset()` is implemented with a single assembly instruction on a RISC processor, that's even more reason to use it, right?

Comment: i have not RISC processor, and i will use #ifdef RISC

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @user2501, initializing to `{0}` or using `memset` is the fastest and correct way.

If you are tempted to use something like `((int *)str)[i] = 0`, do not, this can result in unaligned access.

As an alternative to `memset`, in C99 (and assuming that `int` is 4 bytes) you can use the type punning feature of unions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    char as_string[32];
    int as_int[8];
} foo;

int main(void)
{
    foo x;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        x.as_int[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        printf("%d", x.as_string[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are forced to use pointers and casts, this version uses the heap in order to allocate `str` on an address properly aligned for `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, free */
#include <stdint.h> /* intptr_t (pointer arithmetic using modulo division) */

#define MAX 32

int main(void)
{
    size_t i, align;
    char *ptr, *str;

    align = __alignof__(int);
    ptr = malloc(MAX + align);                 /* MAX + max align distance */ 
    str = ptr + align - (intptr_t)ptr % align; /* now str is properly aligned */
    for (i = 0; i < MAX / sizeof(int); i++)
        ((int *)str)[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("%d\n", str[i]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `__alignof__` is a `gcc` extension, change to `__alignof` if you are under `Visual Studio` or `_Alignof` if you are comfortable with `C11`.

Answer (score -2):

You have to cast the pointer as the int, not the value:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[32];
    for (i = 0; i < 32/sizeof(int); i++)
       ((int *) str)[i] = 0xAABBCCDD; //Be careful of Endianness
}
```

Alternatively:

```
int i;

union block_fill
{
    char arr[24];
    int iarr[6];
};

union block_fill block_arr;

for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    block_arr.iarr[i] = 0x11223344;

for(i=0; i<24; i++)
    printf("%x", block_arr.arr[i]);
```

Comment: And `i` should be incremented by only 1.

Comment: You have **a lot** of undefined behavior in your example.

Comment: Building on @potrzebie, the upper bound should be `32/(sizeof int)` or else you will be running way out of bounds.

Comment: I forgot that casting the pointer as `int *` will affect the pointer arithmetic with `[i]`. I updated the code.

Comment: This is wrong. C doesn't define casting stack memory to arbitrary types.

Comment: Source? So what is the correct way - to make a union binding an int array to a char array?

Comment: your version is almost to the truth, sorry that you got a bad score

Comment: Yes. And assuring that all pointers involved are correctly aligned. And for sake of completeness, this `unsigned int`-to-`int` conversion is implementation-defined. (And `int`s aren't guaranteed to have exactly 32 bits.)

Comment: @RPGillespie Here is my source: http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC+9899-2012

Comment: `unsigned char` is the only type guaranteed to have no padding bits and able to hold all values from 0 to 2^n-1. Larger types can have padding bits and signed types can be 1-complement.

Comment: I still don't understand how my first example could have undefined behavior. Is there a situation where my first example won't behave as expected? Pointing me to the entire standard doesn't help; I'm not going to read the entire thing looking for this one case. Because when I compiled and ran the code on my x86 linux PC, it behaved as expected.